# Insert document in a nested structure

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm working in a Java project using the latests MongoDB's driver. My "schema" is as follows:

```
constructora : [
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "edificios" : [
            {
                "_id":1,
                "data1":"foo"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id":1,
        "edificios": [
            ...
        ]
    }
]
```

All I want to do is to select the subdocument which has the `_id` equals to 1 and then push a subdocument. For example:

```
constructora : [
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "edificios" : [
            {
                "_id":1,
                "data1":"foo",
                "departamento": [
                    {"_id":1, "numero":58},...
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    ....
]
```

The problem is that I can't find the correct method in Java to do this. Can I solve my problem `findAndModify()` or should I use the aggregation framework in this case? Thanks!

Comment: You can try `collection.updateOne(Filters.eq("edificios._id", 1), Updates.set("edificios.$.departamento", departmento array) );` Please check if you may need to include `constructora  _id` to make sure you are picking the right document

Comment: `findAndModify()` is deprecated and not implemented in the `MongoCollection` class. Modern drivers split this into different methods, such as [`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#findOneAndUpdate-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-com.mongodb.client.model.FindOneAndUpdateOptions-com.mongodb.async.SingleResultCallback-). To simply "update" you generally want `updateOne()`, but if you need to return the modified document use `.findOneAndUpdate()`.

Comment: However you really should not "nest arrays". MongoDB cannot address matching indexes at at more than "one level" of arrays. So your design really needs to be "flatter". See the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) for more information.